# Retrieving Data from a field with comma delimitation SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a publications database and I need to fetch some information regarding the author. The author field is such that the authors have been lumped together in one field e.g if a book has two authors called Robert Ludlum and John Grisham, in the database it is saved as Ludlum, R.;Grisham,J.;
My application needs to spool information and retrieve data on books authored by a particular author if they click on their name. I am using this statement to retrieve the data

```
$select = "SELECT tblPublications.Title, tblPublications.Year FROM tblPublications WHERE tblPublications.Authors LIKE '%$sname%'";
```

`$sname` is a variable referring to the surname of the author. The problem arises if two authors share the same surname. however a workaround I am trying to implement is to get the applicationtake the surname, insert a comma, take the first name of a user and get the first letter then combine the result to a stringe and match them to each comma delimited value in the author field e.g if it is Grisham's books I am looking for I use ****Grisham, J.**** in my query.
Any Idea how to do this in PHP,MYSQL?

Comment: You should normalize your schema.  Storing non-atomic data in a single column is bad practice, unless you *absolutely have to for performance reasons* (which is almost never the case, unless you're Google or something.

Comment: You should never ever use CSV data in a database, it will bite you again and again. If a book can have multiple authors, then make a separate authors table and use a link table to link books to authors.

Comment: Where the publications are stored is beyond me. I did not create that database. believe me I know it is chaotic. The authors have been lumped together

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible to redesign the database, you should probably have an authors table and a book_authors table that relates books to authors, so that multiple authors can be associated with each book.  Where is the Last Name coming from that the user clicks?  Is it possible to have the link generated be LastName, First letter of first name? If so then you can probably change the link so it will include the first letter.  But it is still possible to have two authors with the same last name and first letter of first name. So I think the best solution is to have an authors table and a Book_authors table and just store the author id as a hidden field and use that to retrieve the books by the selected author.

Comment: What do you mean by `hidden field` ?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="<?php echo $author_id; ?>" />

Answer (score 1):

Your database design is incorrect, you have not normalized the data.
If you use `like` to search with leading wildcards, you will kill any chance of using an index.
Your only option to fix (if you want to keep the mistaken CSV data) is to convert the table to MyISAM format and put a `FULLTEXT` index on the `authors` field.

You can then search for an author using

```
SELECT fielda, b,c FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(authors) against ('$lastname')
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Of course a better option would be to normalize the database and create a separate table for authors with a link table.

```
TABLE books
------------
id primary key
other book data

TABLE authors
--------------
id primary key
lastname varchar (indexed)
other author data

TABLE author_book_link
----------------------
author_id 
book_id
PRIMARY KEY ab (author_id, book_id)
```

Now you can query using very fast indexes using something like:

```
SELECT b.name, b.ISBN, a.name 
FROM books b
INNER JOIN author_book_link ab ON (ab.book_id = b.id)
INNER JOIN author a ON (a.id = ab.author_id)
WHERE a.lastname = '$lastname'
```

Answer (score 0):

It would entirely depend on what input you are getting from the user.

If the user just types a name, then there isn't much you can do (as there is no guarantee that they will enter it in a correct format for you to parse).

If you are getting them to type in a firstname and lastname however, something like this could be done:

```
<?php
  $firstname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['fname']));
  $surname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sname']));
  $firstletter = substr($_GET['fname'],0,1);
  $sname = $surname.', '.$firstletter;
  $select = "SELECT tblPublications.Title,
             tblPublications.Year 
             FROM tblPublications 
             WHERE tblPublications.Authors LIKE '%$sname%'";
```

Comment: Using leading wildcards with `like` will kill any chance of using an index. If you know the data is "lastname, initials" then a simple search `LIKE '$lastname%'` will give to pretty close results. You can use an outer query to look for occurrences of `$firstname` in these results.

Comment: @Johan As he said in the original question the authors are in the database like `Ludlum, R.;Grisham,J.;` - so in that case if you were searching for `Grisham,J` you wouldn't find it unless you use leading wildcards.

Comment: after rereading the question I see your point. I wonder who downvoted you, because the wildcards will work (and it the only solution that does not require altering the database). +1 to offset the drive-by downvote.

Comment: Probably cause I didn't mention the bad database design :/ Ah well. It's up to the OP if he changes that or not, but if theres already a system built around this database, then it may not be very easy for the OP to change the structure.